# Pandas data conditional mapping best practices

Tags: python, pandas

I have data coming from multiple sources with a mix of rules for how the data is mapped to categorical values. I don't know the best way to do this in pandas. Using `.eval` combined with `.loc` I can make some reasonably complex expressions.

1. Is there a way of assigning `C` in the evaluate expression?
2. Is this a bad idea?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,2,3,4,5], "B" : [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], "Z" : [3, 2, 2, 1, 5]})
df["C"] = 0

x = df.eval("(A > 2) & (B == 0)")
df.loc[x, "C"] = 1

x = df.eval("(C == 0) & (B == 0) & (Z > 0)")
df.loc[x, "C"] = 2

df

    A   B   Z   C
0   1   0   3   2
1   2   1   2   0
2   3   0   2   1
3   4   1   1   0
4   5   0   5   1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's `0` and `1` you want as output then use cast the boolean mask to `int`

```
#df['C'] = 0 is redundant in this case
df['C'] = (df.A.gt(2) & df.B.eq(0)).astype(int)
```

You can use [**`np.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here.

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.A.gt(2)&df.B.eq(0), 1, 0)
```

- `np.where(cond, x, y)` now replace `x` and `y` with values you see fit. values of `x` will usd when `cond` is satisfied, else values of `y`

If you have multiple conditions output corresponding to that condition use [**`np.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

```
condlist = [df.A.gt(2)&df.B.eq(0), other_cond, another_cond]
choicelist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['C'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default_value)
```

- `a` is selected where `condlist[0]` is `True`, `b` is selected when `other_cond` is `True`, likewise for `another_cond`.
- Conditions in `condlist` can be mutually inclusive, then **first** satisfying is selected and it's corresponding value from `choicelist`
- `default_value` is selected when none of the conditions mentioned in `condlist` are `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have this problem of posting example problems that are not sufficiently complex. My primary concern is multiple complex coding rules. Would you mind revising your response?